# JavaEE 6 and Spring

Tags: spring, java-ee-6

I am a JavaEE 6 (JSF 2.0, JPA and EJB 3.1) user, but a newbie in Spring.

Is it a good decision to use Spring with JavaEE 6? (if yes how this will help me?)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your problem. I typically use Spring for at least dependency injection in most Java EE applications I write. Look into the Spring documentation to see what it can do for you.

Start here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-introduction.html

The Spring Framework also provides a heap of other libraries for common Java EE requirements like MVC, Security, AOP etc.

Answer (score 1):

It really does depend on the application you're developing.

JavaEE 6 is really simple to use and provides easy solutions for most of the problems of a simple application. CDI has a conversation scope, its dependency injection mechanism is very powerful and it integrates very well with JSF. EJB is great for persistence and transaction management.

Things do get a little ugly when you have do deal with some other APIs like JTA, JMS, JavaMail, etc. That's when Spring can be of great help. It has libraries for dealing with most of these technologies plus many others (Freemarker, Velocity, JasperReports, Quartz, etc). A point worth mentioning is that you don't need Spring's DI Container to use most of theses integration libraries. Finally, Spring's AOP is great, much more flexible than any of the JavaEE alternatives (but then again, JavaEE's AOP works fine for most of the cases).

As said before, it depends on the problem you're trying to solve. Both are great platforms for developing applications. There's a lot of information on the topic [JavaEE 6 and Spring](http://www.google.com/search?q=javaee%206%20spring) on the web. Do some research and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer a No. Spring should be an alternate for JavaEE. It has tons of useful already implementation which help you a lot to solve your problems, but JavaEE6 is a standard platform which also provides a very good way to work. Depends on what kind of app you're developing to make the decision. Good luck